# React.js: Passing props to props?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, properties

I am learning React via an online course and have stumbled across a situation where a property is attached to another property like so:

```
this.props.property01(this.props.property02)
```

Seeing as the tutor only briefly addresses this line of code I cannot but remain baffled as to what this "concatenation" syntax actually stands for, i.e. what it causes behind the scenes. Coming from Vanilla JS it looks like property02 is being used as an argument for property01 but that seems too simple an answer. That being said, I understand the remaining code quite well.

To provide some context I have created this codepen in which the problem I refer to above is given by `this.props.onDelete(this.props.whichItem);`.

Seeing as I could not find any related questions, I would be grateful for some insightful elaboration on this one.

Comment: Yep. It looks like `property2` is an argument of `property1` why not? As long as you can send function as props like this `<Component onDelete={() => this.deleteItem} />`

P.S. Avoid Bind When Passing Props https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of a React component can be functions. When I see:

```
this.props.property01(this.props.property02)
```

I think that:

- `this.props.property01` is a function.
- `this.props.property02` is passed to the function as an argument.

This means that the component would be used as:

```
<SomeComponent property01={(a) => { /* so something with "a" ... */ } property02={"someValue"} />
```

If `property02` is only used to be passed to `property01` and nothing else I would prefer something like:

```
<SomeComponent property01={(a) => { /* do something with "someValue" ... */ } />
```

Which means that there is no need for a property called `poperty02`.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

> Coming from Vanilla JS it looks like property02 is being used as an argument for property01

That's it, you are correct.

> this.props.property01(this.props.property02)

property01 is a method, property02, the argument.

A more elaborated explanation for anyone else looking at this:

Assume this line is in a component called `MyComponent` and `property01` is a prop in `MyComponent`.

The parent component's render() method, would contain something like this:

```
<MyComponent property01={this.someMethod.bind(this)} />
```

Where `someMethod` belongs to that parent component but it becomes available as `property01` in `MyComponent` (the child component).

Answer (score 0):

If you can understand the basic react code this question will help you because in that code I passed props and state from parent component to the child component. You can play with it try to do whatever you want.

[How to pass state from parent compont to child component in route (react-route-dom) reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782930/how-to-pass-state-from-parent-compont-to-child-component-in-route-react-route-d/43783977?noredirect=1#comment74611526_43783977)